# Github actions: How to customize review deployment screen to say what deployment needs approval

Tags: github, github-actions, github-enterprise

I would like to send essential information about the deployment to the review-deployment screen, so that it is more clear to the reviewer what deployment he is approving for. Example, environment (staging, prod, uat), region (us-west-2, us-west-1), small custom string.

At the moment, if there are 2-3 deployments which needs approval for the same workflow, it is difficult for the reviewer to find which deployment he is approving for. I tried using "url" attribute of environment but it appears after the deployment is approved, not before.

```
environment:
  name: test-approvals-env
  url: ${{format( 'http://env-{0}-tenant-{1}-region-{2}', github.event.inputs.environment , github.event.inputs.tenant_id , github.event.inputs.region )}}
```

[image]